# Why does my jquery linking work in firefox and microsoft edge but not Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, browser

Before that I try and it works text field everything can be validate but when I restart my PC suddenly the validation linking doesn't work. I have try to refresh the browser and try again but it seems to be the same validation doesn't seems to work only in Google Chrome browser.

Here is my code :-

**PHP file**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create New Explore</title>    

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/path/to/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desaru.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css" type="text/css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <br/>
    <?php include('header.html');  ?>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <div id="scrollbox">
    <!-- Content Section -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1><strong>Create New Explore</strong></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    <br/><br/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { // website fully loaded
    $('#submit').click(function() { //if button id=submit click trigger function down
        var name = $('#foldername').val(); //retrieve input for folder name
        var httpvar = 'http://211.25.118.147';
        var defaultfolder = '/resource/';
        //alert(name); get retrieve test name 

        if(name==""){ // if foldername input blank
            alert("Insert folder name");
            }

        else {
            $.ajax( {
            url : "addfolder.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {foldername : name}, //pass input foldername = name(variable declare at the top) foldername name base on html that set
            success: function(result){ //if success will sent the post data
                //alert(result);

                if (result=="success") { //based on output echo addfolder.php

                    alert("File "+name+" has been added");

                    $("#SelectImageFolder option[value='.."+defaultfolder+name+"']").remove();

                    $("#SelectImageFolder").append($('<option>', { //add new options
                        value : ".."+defaultfolder+name ,
                        text : httpvar+defaultfolder+name
                        }))

                    $("#SelectImageFolder option:last").attr("selected", "selected");//auto select the last option

                    }

                else if(result=="fail") {// if the file exist then result will fail to create the file
                    alert("Something wrong happened");
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        }
        })
    });


</script>
<form id="createexplore" action="CreateExploreProcess.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>
            <!--<tr>
                <td>Class</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type='text' name='Class' readonly class='form-control' value='Explore' maxlength="20"/>
                </td>
            </tr>-->
            <!--<tr>
                <td>Placemark</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <Input type='number' name="Placemark" class='form-control' >
                </td>
            </tr>-->
            <tr>
                <td>Category</td>
                <td colspan="2">
           <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
           <select required="true">
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Category..</option>
               <option value="Stay">Stay</option>
               <option value="Dining">Dining</option>
               <option value="Facilities">Facilities</option>
               <option value="ThingstoDo">Things to Do</option>
               <option value="NearbyAttractions">Nearby Attractions</option>
           </select>
           </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sub Category</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
             <select required>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Sub Category...  </option>
               <option value="TheWestinDesaruCoastResort"> The Westin Desaru Coast Resort  </option>
               <option value="Kiosk"> Kiosk  </option>
               <option value="ShuttlePickupPoints"> Shuttle Pickup Points  </option>
               <option value="Rides&Attractions"> Rides & Attractions  </option>
               <option value="ParkingBay"> Parking Bay  </option>
               <option value="DesaruOstrichFarm"> Desaru Ostrich Farm  </option>
               <option value="Restroom"> Restroom  </option>
               <option value="Cafe"> Cafe  </option>
               <option value="AnataraCoastResort&Villas"> Anatara Coast Resort & Villas  </option>
               <option value="Kids"> Kids  </option>
               <option value="DesaruCrocodileFarm"> Desaru Crocodile Farm  </option>
               <option value="Restaurant"> Restaurant  </option>
               <option value="Riverside"> Riverside  </option>
               <option value="InformartionKiosk"> Informartion Kiosk  </option>
               <option value="Amphitheater"> Amphitheater  </option>
               <option value="MainAttractions"> Main Attractions  </option>
               <option value="DesaruCoastAdventureWaterPark"> Desaru Coast Adventure Water Park  </option>
               <option value="Golf"> Golf  </option>
               <option value="LuxuryResorts&Villas"> Luxury Resorts & Villas  </option>
               <option value="HardRockHotelDesaruCoast"> Hard Rock Hotel Desaru Coast  </option>
               <option value="ConferenceCentre"> Conference Centre  </option>
               <option value="Shopping"> Shopping  </option>
               <option value="Spas"> Spas  </option>
               <option value="BeachActivities"> Beach Activities  </option>
               <option value="DesaruFruitFarm"> Desaru Fruit Farm  </option>
               <option value="DisabledToilet"> Disabled Toilet  </option>
               <option value="FirstAid"> First Aid  </option>
               <option value="ChangingRoom"> Changing Room  </option>
               <option value="Locker"> Locker  </option>
               <option value="BabyChangingRoom"> Baby Changing Room  </option>
               <option value="LostandFound"> Lost and Found  </option>
               <option value="MuslimPrayerRoom"> Muslim Prayer Room  </option>
             </select>
             </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Item</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
             <select required>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Item...  </option>
               <option value="Hotel"> Hotel </option>
               <option value="Kiosks"> Kiosks </option>
               <option value="ShuttlePickup"> Shuttle Pickup </option>
               <option value="Rides&Attractions"> Rides & Attractions </option>
               <option value="ParkingBay"> Parking Bay </option>
               <option value="Sightseeing"> Sightseeing </option>
               <option value="Restroom"> Restroom </option>
               <option value="Cafe"> Cafe </option>
               <option value="Kids"> Kids </option>
               <option value="Restaurant"> Restaurant </option>
               <option value="Riverside"> Riverside </option>
               <option value="InformartionKiosks"> Informartion Kiosks </option>
               <option value="Amphitheater"> Amphitheater </option>
               <option value="MainAttractions"> Main Attractions </option>
               <option value="DesaruCoastAdventureWaterPark"> Desaru Coast Adventure Water Park </option>
               <option value="Golf"> Golf </option>
               <option value="ConferenceCentre"> Conference Centre </option>
               <option value="Shopping"> Shopping </option>
               <option value="Spas"> Spas </option>
               <option value="BeachActivities"> Beach Activities </option>
               <option value="DisabledToilet"> Disabled Toilet </option>
               <option value="FirstAid"> First Aid </option>
               <option value="ChangingRoom"> Changing Room </option>
               <option value="Locker"> Locker </option>
               <option value="BabyChangingRoom"> Baby Changing Room </option>
               <option value="LostandFound"> Lost and Found </option>
               <option value="MuslimPrayerRoom"> Muslim Prayer Room </option>
               </select></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" required name='Title' class='form-control' maxlength="150"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Details Header</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" required name="DetailsHeader" class='form-control' maxlength="200"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Details</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea required name="Details" rows="8" class='form-control' maxlength="4000"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Button Promo</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <Input required type="text" name="ButtonPromo" class='form-control' maxlength="20"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Key Features</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <Input required type="text" name="KeyFeatures" class='form-control' maxlength="20"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Features</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea required name="FeaturesList" rows="5" class='form-control' maxlength="1000"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Image Folder</td>
                <td colspan="2"> 
                    <select name="SelectImageFolder" id="SelectImageFolder" class='form-control'>
                                  <option value="selected" selected="selected">Select a folder</option>
                                  <?php
                                        $dirs = glob("../resource/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

                                        // create variable constant url
                                        $httpvar = 'http://211.25.118.147';

                                        foreach($dirs as $val){
                                            $httpcon = str_replace("..",$httpvar,$val);
                                            echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$httpcon."</option>\n";
                                        }
                                    ?>
                    </select><br/>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" required name="foldername" id="foldername" placeholder="Folder Name" class='form-control' maxlength="100" />
                 <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button  type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn"/>Add Folder</button>
                 </span>
              </div></td>
              <script="js/script.js">
              </script>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>List Images</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="file" name="FileListImage" id="FileListImage">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carousel 1</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input required type="file" name="FileCarousel1" id="FileCarousel1">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carousel 2</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="file" name="FileCarousel2" id="FileCarousel2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carousel 3</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="file" name="FileCarousel3" id="FileCarousel3">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carousel 4</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="file" name="FileCarousel4" id="FileCarousel4">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carousel 5</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="file" name="FileCarousel5" id="FileCarousel5">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carousel 6</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="file" name="FileCarousel6" id="FileCarousel6">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Find On Map</td>
                <td colspan="2"> 
                    <Input required type="text" name="FindOnMap" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Call To Book</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <Input type="text" name="CallToBook" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!--<tr>
                <td>Find On Map Ico</td>
                <td> <input type="url" name="FindOnMapIco" class='form-control' /> </td>
                <td><input type="file" name="FileImage" id="FileImage"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Call To Book Ico</td>
                <td> <input type="url" name="CallToBookIco" class='form-control' /></td>
                <td><input type="file" name="FileImage" id="FileImage"></td>
            </tr>-->
            <tr>
             <!--<td >Icon</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="url" name="Icon" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
                </td>
            </tr>-->
            <tr>
                <td>In Park</td>
                <td colspan="2">
             <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
             <select required>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select...  </option>
               <option value="Yes"> Yes  </option>
               <option value="No"> No  </option>
               <option value="">   </option>
             </select>
             </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ticket Entry</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" name="TicketedEntry" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Operation Hours</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea name="OperationHours" rows="6" class='form-control'> </textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ride Details</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea name="RideDetails" class='form-control' maxlength="255"/></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Listing Details</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea name="ListingDetails" class='form-control' maxlength="255"/></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <!--<td>Favourites</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
             <select>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select...  </option>
               <option value="Yes"> Yes  </option>
               <option value="">  </option>
             </select>
             </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FB Like</td>
                <td colspan="2">
             <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
             <select>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select...  </option>
               <option value="Yes"> Yes  </option>
               <option value="">   </option>
             </select>
             </div>
                </td>
            </tr>-->
            <tr>
                <td>More Details</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" name="MoreDetails" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Distance </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" name="DistanceAway" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
           <select required>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Status...  </option>
               <option value="Active"> Active  </option>
               <option value="Inactive"> Inactive  </option>
             </select>
             </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zoom</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="ZoomStart" class='form-control' placeholder="Start" min="14" max="19"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="ZoomEnd" class='form-control' placeholder="End" min="14" max="19"/>
                </td>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>GPS Coordinate</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="Lat" name="Lat" class='form-control' placeholder="Latitude" maxlength="12"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="Lng" name="numeric" class='form-control' placeholder="Longitude" maxlength="12"/>
                </td>
            </td>
            <script src="js/script.js">
            </script>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                <input required type="text" id="hpno" name="Phone" class='form-control' maxlength="12"/>
                </td>
                <script src="js/script.js"></script>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
              <td colspan="2">
                    <input type='submit' id='submit' name='Add' value='Save' class='btn btn-warning'/>
                  <a href='Explore.php' class='btn btn-danger'>Back</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <span id="error_message" class="text-danger"></span>
            <span id="success_message" class="text-success"></span>
        </table>
</form>
  <!-- End Content Section -->
  <?php  include('footer.html');  ?>
    </div> </div>


</body>
</html>
```

And This is my script file

**script.js**

```
$(function() {
    $('#PromoCode').on('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 32)
            return false;
    });
});

$(".input-group").keypress(function(e){
if(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[^_0-9&a-z]/g))
return false;
});

var Phone='';
$("#hpno").keyup(function(e){
if($(this).val().match(/^\+?\d{0,}$/))
{
Phone=$(this).val();
$(this).val(Phone);
}
else{
$(this).val(Phone);
} });
$("#hpno").on('paste',function(){
Phone='';
});

$("#price").on("keyup", function(){
            var valid = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value),
            val = this.value;

           if(!valid){
           console.log("Invalid input!");
           this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
        }
        $("#price").on("blur change",function (event) {
            $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val() || 0).toFixed(2));
            });
});

$(function(){
            var specialKeys = new Array();
            specialKeys.push(46); // allow dot which has keyCode = 46 in specialKeys

            $("#Lat,#Lng").on("blur change",function (event) {
            $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val() || 0).toFixed(8));
            });

            //on keypress you can restrict only number and some special characters
            $("#Lat,#Lng").on("keypress", function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
            var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
            return ret;
            });

            // restrict copy paste
            $("#Lat,#Lng").on("paste drop", function (e) {
            return false;
            });
            });


 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#ValidFrom").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var dt2 = $('#ValidTo');
            var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            dt2.datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 30);
            //sets dt2 maxDate to the last day of 30 days window
            dt2.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', startDate);
            dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
        }
    });
    $('#ValidTo').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you loading 3 different versions of jQuery.js?

Comment: Because some of the text field needed that version..

Comment: Shouldn't be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Your event binding function may not work if the js file is loaded before the dom is loaded.

Please try to include your js file at the bottom of your php file.
Or you can change the event binding function to `$(document).on(event, selector, function)`

Comment: Can you explain the binding function more. Plus I already insert the script linking at the bottom

Comment: For `$(elem).click()`, jquery bind an event to the element once the script is loaded. If the element is not loaded when the script runs, the event is bound to nothing which means the event cannot be triggered.

Comment: Plus another one thing when i insert the script in the php file the validation can work but when I use linking it doesn't work

Comment: what do you mean "linking"

Comment: Like if I insert using <script src="js/script.js"></script> It doesn't work